# conda install -c conda-forge wget

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I tried this command, I am getting this issue, can anybody solve this

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- wget

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Comment: anaconda provides wget only on unix systems, not on windows.

Comment: Are you downloading it in a specific environment?

Comment: Also note that the Python package listed as [`wget` on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) is called [`python-wget` in the Anaconda Cloud repositories](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-wget). So, if you are looking to use `import wget` in Python, then you actually want `conda install -c conda-forge python-wget`

Answer (score 0):

There is a windows variant you can download: https：//eternallybored.org/misc/wget/

Put it in a folder that is your execution folder or in your windows environment path